# Low wattage home server, SoC motherboard

Tags: motherboard, server, power-supply

I'd like to upgrade from a 2GB Rpi while keeping the power bill small.

I have my eyes set on a Biostar J4125NHU. When it comes to IO it's got:

- M.2 M key PCI-E 2.0 x2 slot
- 2x SATA III slots
- some USB ports if i need more drives

The quad-core, low power draw integrated CPU is very important. The dual channel RAM is nice too. I intend to use the PCIe 2.0 x16 slot for a cheap GPU down the line maybe, I'd like to have the option at least.

The only thing amiss is that it supports a maximum of 8GB of RAM. Is there a similar board that can support at least 16?

Also, do you recommend any power supplies?

Thanks.